# Merged file excels overwritting first column in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a lot of files excel, I want to append multiple excel files using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import openpyxl

df = []
for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):

    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    data.index = [os.path.basename(f)] * len(data)
    df.append(data)

df = pd.concat(df)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Excel files have this structure:

[image]

the output is the following:

[image]

Why does python alter the first column when concatenating excel files?

Comment: From what you've posted it looks like it alters the other columns too - can you give a sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: the other columns are not important, because are two different execution of the script. Edit the question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = []
for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1')
    name = os.path.basename(f)
    #create Multiindex for not overwrite original index
    data.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[name], data.index], names=('files','orig'))
    df.append(data)

#reset index for columns from MultiIndex 
df = pd.concat(df).reset_index()
```

Another solution is use parameter `keys` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
files = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
names = [os.path.basename(f) for f in files]
dfs = [pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1') for f in files]

df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=names).rename_axis(('files','orig')).reset_index()
```

What is same as:

```
df = []
names = []
for f in glob.glob(".xlsx"):
    df.append(pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1'))
    names.append(os.path.basename(f))

df = pd.concat(df, keys=names).rename_axis(('files','orig')).reset_index()
```

Last write to excel with no index and no columns names:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False, header=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: The first solution worked! Now I would like delete the first two columns of output excel. how to do it? https://s26.postimg.org/6i84ofdq1/Schermata_a_2017-09-28_15-20-29.png

Comment: You can use `df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', index=False, header=False)`

Comment: Thank you!!! with this instruction `df.drop(['files'], axis = 1, inplace = True)` I can drop "files" column.